# How to edit message when someone reacts to it?

Tags: c#, discord.net

I am trying to have a discord bot edit the message it created when someone reacts to it.

currently I have tried to get the message using these 2 calls

```
var socketMessage = reaction.Message as SocketUserMessage;
var socketMessage = message as SocketUserMessage;
```

The only way I know how to edit messages is using

```
await socketMessage.ModifyAsync(msg => msg.Content = "test [edited]");
```

and that only works with socket user messages. The 2 different ways to get the message that I tried come back as 
Optional.SocketUserMessage or Discord.IMessage.

How do you convert/extract from an optional socket user message or discord.IMessage to a SocketUserMessage?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you used the event client.ReactionAdded to know when an emote was added, the first argument given from that is a Cacheable<IUserMessage, ulong> and from that you can do

```
await message.GetOrDownloadAsync();
```

to get your message